# selenium::remote::driver perl module: RC or webdriver

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am confused about `Selenium::Remote::Driver`'s working.

AFAIK, we need to run selenium server jar file (even if browser and perl program are on same machine) to automate browser. However webdriver (if we use Java or other bindings) does not need server to be running.

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/CHOWES/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.16/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm) clearly states:

> To use this module, you need to have already downloaded and started the Selenium Server (Selenium Server is a Java application).

So my question is: Does `Selenium::Remote::Driver` implement selenium RC? Can we not implement webdriver APIs using perl?
or
APIs mentioned in `Selenium::Remote::Driver` are webdriver APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I think I found the answer.
I found Selenium::Firefox for firefox and similar modules for chrome also.

Now I do not need to use server instance. So Now I came to know that Selenium::Remote::Driver APIs are webdriver APIs.

I got to know this from this [link](http://blog.danielgempesaw.com/post/116904872811/seleniumremotedriver025-now-with-slightly).